# Updating an array of users (having the same username and email)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm maintaining an old ASP application (please don't tell me what you think about ASP, I'm already painfully aware myself) and I'm tasked to easy'fy the user administration.

The **user table** looks like this:

`userID | companyID | loginname | email | endDate | ...`

I built some shorthand functions to set properties for an array of users. Normally the SQL to set, for example, the endDate is simple: `update users set endDate=x where userID in(y)`

The problem lies in that the same user can exist multiply times, ie user 'David' is registered as a user for company C1, C2 and C3. A user is considered "the same" if both email and loginname is the same.

**Question:**

How can I set the same endDate for David, Lisa and Erik (for all companies) at the same time?

Comment: Are you trying to set the same `endDate` for all 3 users?

Comment: yes, Your right. I guess I should have specified that. (done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
UPDATE u 
SET endDate=x 
FROM USERS u 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT loginname, email FROM USERS  WHERE userID IN (y)
) a
ON u.loginname = a.loginname
AND u.email = a.email
```

Comment: Big thanks!  It works!  (I did try myself using a lot of subqueries but never got it to work). Yours is much cleaner!